# MessageFormat not working

Tags: java, messageformat

```
MessageFormat html = new MessageFormat("<div style='text-align:center;'><img src='file:// {0} ' style='-webkit-transform: rotate({1}deg);'></img></div>");
```

I am not able to understand why message format is not working with this string when i use `html.format({"something","someotherthing"});`

Answer (score 8):

Apostrophes must be doubled in a message format pattern:

```
"<div style=''text-align:center;''><img src=''file:// {0} '' style=''-webkit-transform: rotate({1}deg);''></img></div>"
```

Comment: I've been banging my head against the wall for the past couple days trying to figure what wasn't working in my code. Only now do I learn that MessageFormat requires some special attention like this.